# Hard drive working on TV but not on computer(s)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, tv

I have Seagate external powered 1TB hard drive. Its around 5 years old.

Around 1 year before I brought Samsung LED TV which supports USB drives to watch media content. After that I use to switch that Hard drive from TV to Laptop. I will copy some movies in it and watch it on TV.

But from yesterday it stopped detecting properly on my Laptop, but I can still watch movies and all media content on TV without any trouble.

Behavior :

Common behavior:

- When you unplug the USB and plug back in computer doesn't shows anything at all. But when you remove power adapter and plug it again then it shows partially detected drives.

In Windows:

- It will show only one partition kind of detected, but other partition it shows only drive letter but no information (how much memory left) about it. But if I try to open that one partially detected partition, system just hangs up.
- Tried chkdsk but nothing happens
- Can not format it, as any kind of attempt is not able to access hard drive.
- Tried running in Safe Mode, Safe Mode with CMD, removing all "non windows" services from computer then restart. But no success, everything showing the same behavior.

In Mac:

- Shows the same one partition mounted and other one not mounted.
- When you look for drive information it shows for that mounted partition but other one it just shows with fade name.
- Tried to open the mounted one but doesn't show any files in it. (looks same stuck up just like windows did).

In CenOS (linux):

- Shows whole hard drive as one partition and throws error "unable to mount external hard drive"

I strongly believe that it is some corruption in file system & its all about software issue not hardware, because mostly I have movies songs and images in it, all of those can be seen in TV without any trouble.

Does my TV did some kind of reformatting with file system? If so why it was working fine from last one year & how suddenly everything changed?

If it a hardware issue then how can my TV reads it without any delay or problem?

My 1 TB hard disk was full and I have spent a lot of time in collecting those files in it. Can anyone help me to save it?

As an software enggineer, I m a frequent user of StackOverFlow I have high hope on this site.

Comment: It use to hangup on chkdsk command also, m gonna leave it like this today night lets see if it can do something till morning.

Comment: It might be that the TV left some essential files(s) incompletely written (though why should a TV writes to the disk, unless perhaps to write index files for where it last stopped playing?). *Before* CHKDSK discards blocks, I'd suggest trying to clone the drive (direct disk access should be able to clone it), and then reformat it and try to restore what you can from the clone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I my TV doesnt have feature of playing from where it stopped.